# c++ overloading function including bool and integer arguments

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, ambiguous

a simple and I guess easy to answer question (if I did not already got it myself). The following overloaded functions:

```
void BR(const bool set) { backwardReaction_[nReac_] = set; }
bool BR(const int reactionNumber) const { return backwardReaction_[reactionNumber]; }
```

The first function is a setter and the second a getter function. `backwardReaction_` is of type  `std::vector<bool>`. The problem occurs whenever I want to call the second function. Here I get a compiler error `overload function BR(xy) ambigious`.

```
int main()
.
.
const int i = 3;
bool a = chem.BR(i);
```

The compiler error is equal to:

```
chemistryTestProg.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
chemistryTestProg.cpp:74:34: error: call of overloaded ‘BR(const int&)’ is ambiguous
     const bool a = chem.BR(i);
                             ^
In file included from ../../src/gcc/lnInclude/chemistryCalc.hpp:38:0,
                 from ../../src/gcc/lnInclude/chemistry.hpp:38,
                 from chemistryTestProg.cpp:35:
../../src/gcc/lnInclude/chemistryData.hpp:266:18: note: candidate: void AFC::ChemistryData::BR(bool)
             void BR(const bool);
                  ^~
../../src/gcc/lnInclude/chemistryData.hpp:322:22: note: candidate: bool AFC::ChemistryData::BR(int) const
                 bool BR(const int) const;
                      ^~
```

I guess that I get the problem because of the types `bool` and `int` which are identically (`true => int(1), false => int(0)`. As I am changing the getter name to, e.g., `bool getBR(const int reactionNumber) {...}` everything works fine. So I guess the problem is about the similarities of the `bool` and `int` treatment within c++. I also tried a variety of different calls such as:

```
const bool a = chem.BR(4)
const bool a = chem.BR(int(5))
const bool a = chem.BR(static_cast<const int>(2))
bool a = chem.BR(...)
```

Thus, I think it is really related to the `bool` and`int` overloading arguments. Nevertheless, I made a quick search and did not find too much about these two overload types and resulting problems. Tobi

Comment: Re: "The first function is a setter and the second a getter function" -- yes, that's true, but they aren't a pair, so shouldn't have the same name. A getter function should show you what the corresponding setter did. So `void BR(int reactionNumber, bool set) { backwardReaction_[reactionNumber] = set; }` and `bool BR(int reactionNumber) { return backwardReaction_[reactionNumber]; }` go together. `void BR(bool set)` should have a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you declared `BR(int)`, but not `BR(bool)`, to be `const`. Then when you call `BR(int)` on a non-const object, the compiler has two conflicting matching rules: parameter matching favours `BR(int)`, but `const`-ness matching favours `BR(bool)`.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks. If I remove `const` from the `BR(int)` it works. Eitherway, I can make the object itself `const`. Thanks for clarifying. So I was wrong.